# Large bulk_save_objects of SQLAlchemy "hangs" the code

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

Running on a 32GB RAM, I have code that works perfectly and bulk saves to MySQL when it comes to 700,000 total rows to save, taking up about 10% of the RAM when doing it in about 10 seconds.

Same machine, same code, same everything hangs and does not give an error, does not seem to do anything at all, when my same bulk save to the same MySQL database is 10x as large (7 million rows). I've waited as long as 8 hours for it to complete the operation, but there is no sign of RAM/CPU/IO activity at all.

Any ideas/solutions on what to change the bulk_save_objects of sqlalchemy to in order for this operation to go smoothly with even larger (even much larger) sizes?

Comment: I'd consider committing in batches, but if there is really no sign of activity on the machine I would check for locks.

Comment: Can you explain your "locks" idea?

Comment: I'm not an expert on MySQL internals, but in general, transactions may attempt to get locks on tables to perform updates; if another transaction already has a lock on the target table, the original transaction must wait  for it to be released.  A situation called _deadlock_ may arise where transaction A has a lock on table1 and wants a lock on table2, but transaction B has a lock on table2 and wants a lock on table1.  Without intervention, both transactions may wait for ever,  Searching for "detecting ln locks MySQL"  or similar should  get you plenty of results.

Comment: I have looked into this and spent more time debugging the code. It's a multiprocessing dump of some huge dfs, and out of 16 CPU-s it seems that 2 never finish the dumping process. This must be a deadlock indeed! Thank you for your help! :) I'm new here, if I'm supposed to "mark this question as resolved" somehow, or give you "thanks" for it, let me know how :)